# Using 4 XYZ points, make a surface?

Tags: geometry, functions

I have 4 points (Vector3f). By connecting them, i make a surface, when the edges that are used to create that face are lines, i can easily make them out. But when it comes to arc, the edges are curved and iam struggling to find out if a point exists on that surface or not.

The approach of splitting that face into triangles and checking leads to over consumption of time. Please suggest me a Best Way To Do So....

This question has been asked around, but I cannot find the answer! I'm getting pretty desperate, and creating 4 triangle planes as an estimate just doesn't cut it

Comment: This is rather vague---what properties do you want the surface to have?

Comment: I just want to be able to check if an external point (with an xyz val) is above or below this surface (i.e. the z val is greater or less than)

Comment: the only requirement of the surface is that it is defined by the four vertices.

Comment: But there are many surfaces that include these four points, and a given external point may be above some of these and below others (and off to the side, too, if there are no further conditions). How do you want to choose a surface?

Comment: I thought this might be the problem. I suppose the most 'plane-like'. The smoothest surface possible

Comment: Again, there are lots of smooth surfaces. Four points not all in the same plane determine a sphere, which is one option. One can also just form the tetrahedron whose vertices are the given points, but it will have edges that are not smooth.

Comment: I guess a bit of context would help. These four points have lines draw between them, and there are about 60,000 points, which form a terrain. I have to check if your point (camera) is above or below the terrain (which is draw by connecting these points with lines). so when you're very close to the points, I want to check if you would be below the 'terrain'

Comment: so something linear that doesn't change very quickly. I'm just not sure if such a thing exists

Comment: Do the $(x, y)$ coordinates form, e.g., the corners of a square in the plane? Or is it something more complicated?

Comment: posted an answer, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that best fitted my needs was by taking the 'rectangle' and splitting it into two triangles. Using the 6 points (3 for each triangle), I made two planes. I checked if the point was below EITHER plane, and report if it was. This seemed to give the smoothest results. You could put any surface between those 4 points, but this takes up the least computation and is the smoothest (that I could think of anyway!), thanks Travis for your help.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help, good luck with your project.